# SQL SMO assemblies not being deployed when publishing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, configuration

I've got a little problem regarding the deployment of a number of assemblies related to SMO. I have the following 5 references in my project:

[image]

Each one is a .dll in a libraries folder which is where the references were added from and each is set to Copy Local = true. The project file shows all this is in order, for example:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\Libraries\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Problem is, every time I publish from Visual Studio on my PC, the assemblies aren't copied. Same thing when I publish via TeamCity (which definitely doesn't have SQL Server or the SMO SDK installed). I can copy the assemblies over manually and things run just fine (no GAC dependency), but obviously I'd like to encapsulate this in the deployment process.

What could be stopping these assemblies from publishing?

Comment: Hi, I would try to switch copy local to false and true again, not sure but the private True you have in your project file doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: I started out with the default of Copy Local = false with no joy. The <private> element is added after setting Copy Local to true.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you're not supposed to just copy DLL when deploying an SMO-based application. See this link: [Distributing an Application That Uses SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713979.aspx). I quote:

> If you develop an application that uses SQL Server Management Objects,
>   you need to make sure that the necessary support files are present on
>   the computer with the application. The SQL Server 2008 feature pack
>   contains a redistributable package for the SQL Server Management
>   Objects.

You will need to get the SharedManagementObjects.msi from this download link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978

Comment: I did look at that earlier, but it appears to require a server install and I'm trying to get SMO self-contained within the app. As I mentioned earlier, so long as those SMO assemblies make it into the bin at the destination, things work fine. I'm just not clear on why they refuse to deploy in the publish process.

Comment: @Troy - This is not a "server install", it's the official way of doing it, server or workstation. BTW, I'm not sure you actually have the legal rights to distribute these assemblies your own way. But that is your own concern, not mine :-) Could you explain what is this "publish process" you're speaking about?

Comment: Ok, so call it "target environment install", point is I read the intention as being installed via msi which makes deployment into some environments trickier then including the assemblies directly. The publish process is just web deploy either via Visual Studio publish feature or directly by msbuild. I'll have to read the fine print, but the doc on the link you shared does talk about "a redistributable component as part of their application".

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft employee Monica Rivera confirmed in an [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0469db8-f0b8-4289-a314-6bcfcb9aec27/microsoftsqlserversmodll-issue?forum=sqlsmoanddmo) that it is fine to bundle the DLLs with your application:

> Here's another way. You can choose to include the necessary DLLs in your build from the VS project. If you select the reference in the project and change the Property "Copy Local" to True, the corresponding DLL will be included in the build.

So, according to the MSDN thread, both solutions are fine.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Comment: @RadimKöhler This answer is *significantly* more than a link. It asserts that it's OK to use the feature pack *or* distribute DLLs directly. The link is only provided as source material to back up this claim.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN ok.. I was wrong, you are right... good luck, sir